# What can be done with scroll-snap-type

Tags: html, css, scroll

What I'm am trying to do is to use the `scroll-snap-type` property properly

---

I don't quite get why this code works

```css
html,
body {
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
}

.child {
  scroll-snap-align: start none;
  border: 3px dashed black;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="child">1</div>
<div class="child">2</div>
<div class="child">3</div>
<div class="child">4</div>
```

But this one doesn't

```css
.slider {
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
}

.child {
  scroll-snap-align: start none;
  border: 1px dashed black;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <div class="child">1</div>
  <div class="child">2</div>
  <div class="child">3</div>
  <div class="child">4</div>
</div>
```

I tried :

- Adding a height to the slider
- Changing the overflow-y

But none of the below option seems to work, I really don't understand why is it so

---

Because What I'm trying to achieve is a page with normal scroll then scroll-snap

```css
.slider {
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
}

.child {
  scroll-snap-align: start none;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<h2>Normal Scrolling page</h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellendus odit laudantium esse saepe, minus eos rem! Dolor nobis saepe, exercitationem, quasi est, quia reiciendis excepturi culpa tempora perspiciatis dolorum delectus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit
  amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellendus odit laudantium esse saepe, minus eos rem! Dolor nobis saepe, exercitationem, quasi est, quia reiciendis excepturi culpa tempora perspiciatis dolorum delectus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing
  elit. Repellendus odit laudantium esse saepe, minus eos rem! Dolor nobis saepe, exercitationem, quasi est, quia reiciendis excepturi culpa tempora perspiciatis dolorum delectus.</p>
<h2>This section below is scroll-snapping ⬇️ (or should be)</h2>
<div class="slider">
  <div class="child">1</div>
  <div class="child">2</div>
  <div class="child">3</div>
  <div class="child">4</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The height on the container is not enough: you need to also set `overflow-y: scroll`

```css
* { padding: 0; margin: 0}

.slider {
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.child {
  scroll-snap-align: start none;
  border: 1px dashed black;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <div class="child">1</div>
  <div class="child">2</div>
  <div class="child">3</div>
  <div class="child">4</div>
</div>
```

---

Furthermore, if you want to always stop the scroll on each slide also add `scroll-snap-stop: always;` for the `.child` elements

```css
* { padding: 0; margin: 0}

.slider {
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.child {
  scroll-snap-align: start none;
  scroll-snap-stop: always;
  border: 1px dashed black;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <div class="child">1</div>
  <div class="child">2</div>
  <div class="child">3</div>
  <div class="child">4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your time i does the trick.
i didn't know the `scroll-snap-stop` property

Answer (score 1):

Because scrollbar (or overflown element) in both cases is `<html>`

Putting scrollbar on `.slider` it changes behaviour:

```css
.slider {
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
  max-height: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.child {
  scroll-snap-align: start none;
  border: 1px dashed black;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <div class="child">1</div>
  <div class="child">2</div>
  <div class="child">3</div>
  <div class="child">4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello thanks for your time, this works but prevent me from scrolling when the slider takes all the screen